# How we can solve unwanted offset in onEnd gesture in swiftUI 2.0

Tags: swiftui

I have this codes for swipe the rows inside a scrollview, at some first try it works fine, but after some scrolling and swipe it starts giving some value for offset even almost zero, and it makes red background shown in edges! I know, probably would some of you came with padding solution up and it would work and cover unwanted red background but even with this unconvinced solution, the text would seen offseted from other ones! I am thinking this is a bug of SwiftUI, otherwise I am very pleased to know the right answer.thanks

[image]

```
import SwiftUI




struct item: Identifiable
    {
        var id      = UUID()
        var name    : String
        var offset  : CGFloat = 0
    }



struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    
    @State var Items: [item] = []
    
    
    func findIndex(item: item) -> Int
    {
        for i in 0...Items.count - 1
        {
            if item.id == Items[i].id
            {
                return i
            }
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        

        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false)
        {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading)
            {
                
                ForEach(Items) { item in
                    
                    
                    
                    ZStack
                    {
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.red)
                        
 
                        HStack
                        {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading)
                            {
                                
                                Text(item.name)
                                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.yellow)
                                    .offset(x: item.offset)
                                    .gesture(
                                        DragGesture()
                                            .onChanged({ (value) in
                                                Items[findIndex(item: item)].offset = value.translation.width
  
                                            })
                                            .onEnded({ (value) in

                                                Items[findIndex(item: item)].offset = 0

                                            }))
                                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear()
        {
            for i in 0...10
            {
                Items.append(item(name: "item " + String(i)))
            }
        }
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because drag gesture is handled even if you try to scroll vertically and horizontal transition is applied to your offset. So the solution is to add some kind of boundary conditions that detects horizontal-only drag.

Here is just a simple demo (you can think about more accurate one). Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 as kind of enough for demo.

```
DragGesture()
.onChanged({ (value) in
    // make offset only when some limit exceeds or when it definitely sure
    // that you drag in horizontal only direction, below is just demo
    if (abs(value.translation.height) < abs(value.translation.width)) {
        Items[i].offset = value.translation.width
    }
})
```

**Update:** forgot that I changed also to use indices to avoid afterwards finding by id, so below is more complete snapshot

```
ForEach(Items.indices, id: \.self) { i in
    ZStack
    {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
        HStack
        {
            VStack(alignment: .leading)
            {
                
                Text(Items[i].name)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .offset(x: Items[i].offset)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ (value) in
                            if (abs(value.translation.height) < abs(value.translation.width)) {
                                Items[i].offset = value.translation.width
                            }
                        })
                        .onEnded({ (value) in
                            Items[i].offset = 0.0
                        }))
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, because it does not separate distance by axis.